# How to prevent href attribute getting read by NVDA screenreader?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, wcag2.0, nvda

NVDA in IE11 is reading url of Link specified as href attribute. Role tab is used on the link. This is causing issue in screen-reader compliance. How to prevent href getting read? Is it a browser and screen-reader compliance issue?

Comment: Could you post the HTML please? It might be that making a link a tab nullifies the link, but the context would help work out what it is taking as the accessible name of that element.

Comment: Also, make sure you have an actual text inside your link, or use title attribute or aria-label. Otherwise it will read the href

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on http://accessibleculture.org/articles/2010/08/aria-tabs/
you have to remove href from the tab